Activex control not registered on this computer
Friends There is a test device that communicates with a computer in the company I work for. The tests performed with this tester can be received as a report via Microsoft Excel. I use it on my old computer, but when I install the software on the new computer, I have a problem in the reports section. I get the following error. What is your suggestion about the subject?
I use Windows 11 Pro as operating system.
Translated with DeepL.com (free version)
enter image description here
enter image description here
I did download this plugin: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms968493(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN
I did try this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N2CdJRN1ai0
